# How do I use Lebesgue integration theory to evaluate $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \exp(-\sin^{2}(nx))x^{n}\: dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I want to use Lebesgue integration theory to evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \exp(-\sin^{2}(nx))x^{n}\: dx.$$

At first I thought about using the monotone convergence theorem, but I realized that the functions $f_{n}=\exp(-\sin^{2}(nx))x^{n}$ are not increasing.

It seems that it should be the case that I can use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem here. I'm not sure about my answer, however, and need to verify if this is right:

Certainly the functions are dominated by $1$. That is, $|f_{n}| \le 1$ holds on $[0, 1]$ and the sequence $f_{n} \to 0$ pointwise a.e. on $[0, 1]$ so we have $$\int_{0}^{1} \exp(-\sin^{2}(nx))x^{n}\: dx \to 0.$$

Comment: $0 \leq\exp(-\sin^{2}(nx))\leq 1$ so you don't  need any theorem.

Comment: Isn't it what  geetha meant?